# Deploy from Maven to Nexus got error: ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

Tags: maven, nexus

http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/nexus-repository/

I am following the above link to setup Maven and Nexus, everything new. I couldn't left a new comment there so I post here.

After so long, I am in another company, when I tried to setup a simple sample in my local PC, I got this error in "mvn deploy" to the simple Maven my-app sample. I installed the simple Nexus Open Source w/o Tomcat.

[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.mycompany.app:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Access denied to: localhosts:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richard Seddon  resolved my issue in nexus-users group.

Add this to nonProxyHosts:
    localhost

Comment: I add the same problem with gitlab, hope my comment guide someone in the future

Answer (score 4):

In your settings.xml located in **MAVEN_HOME/conf** you have to add in servers section

```
<server>
  <id>nexus-releases</id>
  <username>deploy</username>
  <password>123456</password>
</server>
```

And in your pom must looks like

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
    <id>nexus-releases</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Ids have to be the same.

Comment: I've configured this in C:\Documents and Settings\jhu06\.m2\settings.xml, I thought this will overwrite the default one? I tried to add the same to MAVEN_HOME/conf, but got the same result.

Comment: have you changed the default password in nexus? user: deploy, password: deploy123

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authorized to run deployment. This is done by having the server section in your settings.xml. Check out the [Nexus eval guide](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval.html), specifically the [publishing section](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval-proxy-publish.html#_publishing_components) and the [sample projects](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples) in there for more detail.

Comment: [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\my-app\target\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Installing C:\my-app\target\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Documents and Settings\jhu06\.m2\repository\com\mycompa
ny\app\my-app\1.0-SNAPSHOT\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\my-app\pom.xml to C:\Documents and Settings\jhu06\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\app\my-app\1.0-SNAPS
HOT\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

Comment: The problem is here: why it's downloading something hasn't been added? Everything is brand new, so there is nothing in Nexus yet.

Comment: [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ my-app ---
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-meta
data.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.mycompany.app:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshots (http:/
/localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Access denied to: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositorie
s/snapshots/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.