# Error "Could not transfer metadata" running Maven deploy with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have 2 Maven projects, which are deployed daily in a Nexus snapshots repository by Jenkins builds.
For one project, everything works fine. 
For the second one, I have the error below every time Jenkins runs `mvn deploy` :

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ my-second-project ---
[INFO] Downloading: http://my.nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/fr/domain/my-second-project/0.18.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata fr.domain:my-second-project:0.18.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to my.nexus (http://my.nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Access denied to: http://my.nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/fr/domain/my-second-project/0.18.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

The 2 projects have exactly the same version.

I tried to run `mvn help:effective-settings` on both Jenkins builds, instead of `mvn deploy` : it returns exactly the same settings for both projects. But one deploys on Nexus and the other does not...

***Edit***: `mvn help:effective-pom` doesn't show any helpful difference either. Except for the project name and some dependencies, they are the same.

In the case of the second project, it has never been deployed on Nexus. So metadata doesn't exists yet. But I tried to tail the nexus `request.log` file, and it's never hit when Jenkins runs `mvn deploy`on the second project. I have no trace of that call.

Does anyone have an idea ?

---

**Edit**: 
I've finally found out that the company proxy is throwing the "Forbidden" error. Which is weird, because in the `settings.xml` Maven configuration file, I have the following :

```
<proxy>
    <id>****</id>
    <active>true</true>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>**********</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>my.nexus|127.0.0.1|...</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

The job that fails is ignoring the "nonProxyHosts" part : the proxy defined in the config is called and throws the error. The job that builds normally doesn't call the proxy (expected behaviour).

I'm still looking for ideas about the reason for this behaviour...

Comment: Run [`mvn help:effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) instead and compare the differences

Comment: I did too : nothing relevant. The only differences were the project name and some dependencies.

Comment: Looks like a credential error. Have a look at the second answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196514/deploy-from-maven-to-nexus-got-error-reasonphraseforbidden if they use the same settings then the pom for that project may be configured incorrectly

Comment: The 2 projects pom inherit from the same parent pom which declares the distributionManagement. The effective pom of the 2 projects are identical on this point.

Comment: This is a credential error, either no credentials are being sent or incorrect ones are.  Make sure the ID in the distributionManagement URL matches the ID in the "server" setting in your settings.xml.

Comment: How could this be OK for one project and KO fir the other one, using exactly the same configuration ? Anyway, I have news concerning that problem : I'm going to edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is issue with the credentials.

find out which settings.xml maven is using.
mvn -v

then in that file update the section with correct credentials

```
 <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>deployment</username>
      <password>deployment</password>
    </server>
```

Now try it:)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this is to delete the dependencies or artifacts which maven has appended with the .lastUpdated prefix.  Only after that can you successfully Update Dependencies of your maven project.

For Unix Users:

1. find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
2. Right click your project and choose Update Dependencies

For Windows Users:

1. CD (change directory) to `<user-directory>\.m2\repository`
2. execute this command `for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i`
3. Right click your project and choose `Update Dependencies`

Comment: your solution works for local machine... what if it's a jenkins server and its a jenkins build.. and if you don't have access to the build server.   mvn clean install will remove the workspace and creates a fresh copy every time.. even with mvn clean install the issue is not resolved