# maven build error for spring security dependencty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i am getting maven build error for my spring boot project i added spring security in my pom.xml but complete maven build

Dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to 
SpringFramework (https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/): Authorization failed for 
https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml 403 
Forbidden
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.0-M1 is 
missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.0-M1 is 
missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.0-M1 is 
missing, no dependency information available

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gtt-v2-sample-track-salesorders-service: Could not 
resolve dependencies for project com.sap.gtt.v2:gtt-v2-sample-track-salesorders- 
service:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.0-M1, 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.5.0-M1, 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.0-M1: Failure to find 
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.5.0-M1 in 
https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/ was cached in the local repository, resolution 
will not be reattempted until the update interval of SpringFramework has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

do i need to change anything, how to resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

change the version of the spring boot

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to this

Answer (score 0):

There are some vulnerabilities for version 5.5.0 and 5.5.1.
See the details here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/5.5.1

Please use the suggested version 5.6.2 (which doesn't have those vulnerabilities) in your code.

Change the version and then run mvn -U clean install to update the spring dependency version. If you are behind a proxy, ensure that you have the proxy details added in your settings.xml as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35087524/3981539)